# How can i use a usb controller in custom written C games or programs

Tags: c, visual-c++, usb

**Problem**
Having grown tired of writing functions to move sprites and characters diagonally and assigning keys that do not flow with the 4 main directional keys(UP, DOWN, LEFT, RIGHT) such as W,A,S,D is a bit of a drag and a bore. However i recently got this usb controller http://www.logitech.com/en-us/gaming/controllers/devices/288 and i would like to be able to add its usage to my console based games or windows applications. AS it has the analog sticks that support comfortable diagonal movement.

**Workaround/Possible Solution**
There is a fair amount of documentation on doing this in C# but i am more comfortable in C and know next to nothing about C#.

**Question**
Is it possible in C without additional libraries and if so how can i could use the usb controller support in my programs(and add the functionality to my future projects). Any resources or tips are much appreciated. Linux or Windows solutions are welcome. thanks in advance.

Comment: I would probably start with [libusb](http://libusb.sourceforge.net/api-1.0/group__syncio.html#_details). Yes, it is an additional library (over nothing) but these days it is probably nearly ubiquitous.

Comment: better than nothing. thank you.

Comment: umm... either ask for more info, or accept an answer please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Windows you may try [Direct Input](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DirectInput), or *XInput* it has excellent support for Joysticks and GamePads. It is also used in XBox development. Many Game Projects use this, here is a complete [list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XInput_games)

Another good option is [SDL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_DirectMedia_Layer), it has adequate support for GamePads (which is built on top of DirectInput on Windows Systems) and is *Platform-Independent* , so that may be an advantage. Also I *think* [Allegro](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allegro_library) supports them, but I'm not sure.

NOTE: Sorry, if you don't intend to reinvent the wheel and write a driver and api for every damn GamePad in the market, you'll *have* to use an additional library.

Comment: i went with SDL then gradually transitioned to SFML.. thanks!